How can I prove that $C_{\Phi\circ\Psi^*}=(I\otimes\overline{\Psi})(C_\Phi)$?

$\mathrm{Suppose~}\Phi,\Psi:\mathcal{M}_n\to\mathcal{M}_n\text{ are linear maps}\ \text{and}\ C \ \text{is the Choi matrix}.$
$\text{Show that }C_{\Phi\circ\Psi^*}=(I\otimes\overline{\Psi})(C_\Phi),\text{ where }\overline{\Psi}\text{ is the linear map defined by }\overline{\Psi}(X)=\overline{\Psi(\overline{X})}\text{ for all }X\in\mathcal{M}_n.$

By the way, $\Psi^*$ is the adjoint linear map of $\Psi$.
It seems that some linear map (I believe $\Psi$) will "jump" into the other tensor's factor (by looking at the Choi matrix definition as a sum of elementary tensors, as described below), but I don't know how. I tried to bring in the trace operation desperately but with no success.
$$C_\Phi =\sum_{i,j=1}^n\Phi(E_{i,j})\otimes E_{i,j}$$

Here are three properties that will be helpful:

Standard Matrix Basis Expansion of $X \in \mathcal{M}_n$: $\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}\def\Id{\operatorname{Id}}X = \sum_{ij} \tr(E_{ij}^\ast X) E_{ij}$
Definition of Adjoint: $\tr(\Psi(X)^\ast Y) = \tr(X^\ast \Psi^\ast(Y))$
$\tr(X^\ast) = \overline{\tr(X)}$

You want to use the first property on $C_{\Phi \circ \Psi^\ast}$ in some way, then you can do a "jump" like you mention. All the steps are below.

 $$\begin{aligned} C_{\Phi \circ \Psi^\ast} &= \sum_{ij} \Phi(\Psi^\ast(E_{ij})) \otimes E_{ij} \\ &= \sum_{ij} \Phi\left(\sum_{kl} \tr(E_{kl}^\ast \Psi^\ast(E_{ij})) E_{kl}\right) \otimes E_{ij} \\ &= \sum_{kl} \sum_{ij} \Phi(E_{kl}) \otimes \tr(E_{kl}^\ast \Psi^\ast(E_{ij})) E_{ij} \\ &= \sum_{kl} \Phi(E_{kl}) \otimes \left(\sum_{ij} \tr(\Psi(E_{kl})^\ast E_{ij}) E_{ij} \right) \\ &= \sum_{kl} \Phi(E_{kl}) \otimes \left(\sum_{ij}\overline{\tr(E_{ij}^\ast \Psi(\overline{E_{kl}}))} E_{ij}\right) \\ &= \sum_{kl} \Phi(E_{kl}) \otimes \overline{\Psi}(E_{kl}) \\ &= (\Id \otimes \overline{\Psi})(C_{\Phi}) \end{aligned}$$

